# Map Linq groupby count to C# entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, count, group-by

I have this sql query that performs a groupby on a single field. It then counts the groupby's. So far so good.

```
select type, count(*) 
from myTable
group by type
//Result    
//TypeA = 5
//TypeB = 3
```

However, I am having trouble performing this query with Linq as I need to map the outcome of Count() to a specific entity.

The entity I want to map the count to:

```
public class MyEtity(){
    public int TypeACount {get; set;}
    public int TypeBCount {get; set;}
}
```

The linq query I currently use which

```
MyEntity test = data
    .GroupBy(c => c.type)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity (){
        TypeACount = g.Where(d => d.type == "A").Count(),
        TypeBCount = g.Where(d => d.type == "B").Count()
    });
```

#### Extra info

Based on some answers, a little extra info. My original plan was to use following.

```
var firstResults = session.Query<MyEntity>()
    .Where(//several date filter conditions)
    .ToList();

return new MyEntity() {
    TypeACount = firstResults.Where(s => s.type == "A").Count(),
    TypeBCount = firstResults.Where(s => s.type == "B").Count()
};
```

This works, but table queried is rather large and the query took quite some time. Based on a colleagues feedback I was asked if the query couldn't be made in to 1 part instead of separating it. The idea being that the query counting logic would remain in SQL rather than in C#. I don't know if that would actually be faster, but that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Is the `c.TypeOfUsage` and `d.type` supposed to be the same property in your LINQ query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map after you get the information

```
var results = data
    .Where(c => c.TypeOfUsage == "A" || c.TypeOfUsage == "B")
    .GroupBy(c => c.TypeOfUsage)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        Type = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();

MyEntity test = new MyEntity
{
    TypeACount = results.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "A")?.Count ?? 0,
    TypeBCount = results.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "B")?.Count ?? 0
}
```

Or if you don't have C# 6

```
var a = results.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "A");
var b = results.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "B");
MyEntity test = new MyEntity
{
    TypeACount = a == null ? 0 : a.Count,
    TypeBCount = b == null ? 0 : b.Count
}
```

Another option would be to use a constant group by.

```
MyEntity test= data
    .Where(c => c.TypeOfUsage == "A" || c.TypeOfUsage == "B")
    .GroupBy(c => 1)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity 
    {
        TypeACount = g.Where(d => d.TypeOfUsage == "A").Count(),
        TypeBCount = g.Where(d => d.TypeOfUsage == "B").Count()
    }).Single();
```

This would be more like the following SQL

```
select 
    sum(case when typeOfUseage = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) AS TypeACount
    , sum(case when typeOfUseage = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) AS TypeBCount
from myTable
```

Comment: I like that approach. My query is also a lot faster now. Also smart use of the coalesce operator there.

Answer (score 1):

why not the clasic way?, I do not see in your query the reason for group by or Select;

```
            var entity=new MyEntity()

            entity.TypeACount = data.Count(a => a.TypeOfUsage == "A"),
            entity.TypeBCount =data.Count(b => b.TypeOfUsage == "B")
```

Comment: Assuming that `data` is some type of EF `IQueryable` or `DbSet` that results in two DB calls.

Comment: he can use a temp variable like `var temp=data.Select(b => b.TypeOfUsage).ToList()` and then he can call `Count` on the temp variable, only one call to db.

Comment: That would also be inefficient if there are a lot of rows.  It's just best practice to let the DB do as much of the work as possible and return the least amount of data needed.

Comment: @juharr you are right! is more efficient your way, thanks!